# xSQLserver DSC module

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Does anone know how I can modify the [MSFT_xSQLServerSetup module on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/xSQLServer) to take on the services accounts in the following formats:

```
$SQLServer = $env:computername
$DomainName = $env:USERDOMAIN
$DBServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "DE"
$AgtServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "AG"
$FTServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "FT"
$RSServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "RS"
$ASServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "AS"
$ISServiceName = "$DomainName\$SQLServer" + "IS"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to edit any file of the module. You are passing in the service accounts when you build the configuration for the xSqlServerSetup resource.